# Query to select rows with minimum distinct value of a column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to select row with minimum value of column B for each row of column A but it should be distinct from the other values that so far have been selected for column A. So the order of A maters. Also if the B is used up and none is left then the later values for A should be NULL or not appearing in the result.

Both A and B are numerical (or time stamp).
example:

```
A   | B | 
----+---+
1   | 3 | 
1   | 5 | 
1   | 6 | 
2   | 3 | 
2   | 5 | 
9   | 3 |
9   | 5 |
```

So the desired result is:

```
A   | B | 
----+---+
1   | 3 | 
2   | 5 |
```

`select A, min(B) group by A` obviously doesn't work because I don't want B to be repeated. `Distinct` also doesn't work because the rows are already distinct. I couldn't really find any question similar to this anywhere.
The actual data I am working with is the database of timeseries on redshift so A and B are timestamps. CTE's would be specifically welcome.

Comment: then `1, 6` is also distinct.

Comment: @zealous yes but 6 is not the minimum value to be assigned to 1.

Comment: @zealous my bad. I just corrected my question.

Comment: Should the minimum for a == 2 be three?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What if there is also A = 3 with values for B: 3 and 5 only? 3 and 5 are already assigned.

Comment: @darrendanvers no as I said the values of B should not be repeated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not sure why you need that. It is on redhshift. Simple time series data. A and B is the result of joining two time series data on specific values and A and B values are timstamps. I am basically looking to find unique pairs of timestamps.

Comment: How big is this table? I'm wondering if this can be done recursively.

Comment: @shawnt00 it is not that big about a million rows

Comment: @Bahman . . . So solve this with a SQL-only solution requires recursive CTEs.  Redshift does not offer any functionality like that, so you will need a programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

First I thought this could be solved with `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER PARTITION BY B DESC)` however there is a problem, the numbers in B should not be repeated.

At the moment the only thing that comes to mind is to make temporary tables, I know this is not the best way, but you can probably improve it

```
DECLARE @Tabla1 TABLE(A INT) 
DECLARE @Tabla2 TABLE(B INT)
DECLARE @Tabla3 TABLE(A INT, B INT)
INSERT INTO @Tabla1 SELECT DISTINCT A FROM PRUEBA

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Tabla1) > 0
BEGIN
  DECLARE @A INT, @B INT;
  SET @A = (SELECT TOP 1  * FROM @Tabla1);
  SET @B = (SELECT MIN(B) FROM PRUEBA WHERE A = @A AND B NOT IN(SELECT * FROM @Tabla2));
  INSERT INTO @Tabla2 VALUES (@B)
  DELETE FROM @Tabla1 WHERE A = @A
  INSERT INTO @Tabla3 SELECT A, B FROM PRUEBA WHERE A = @A AND B = @B
END

SELECT * FROM @Tabla3
```

Maybe you can use a cursor, but you would have to be calculated that takes more computational expense, the cursor or the temporary tables

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a "find the diagonal" problem.  You need to know the rank of B within A and the rank of A within all.  I believe this works for the data given:

```
select A, B from (
  select row_number() over (partition by A order by B) as RN,
    dense_rank() over (order by A) as DR.
    A, B
    from <table> )
where RN = DR;
```

For more complex cases this solution will get more complex.

Addendum:
Because I know it will be asked and this is an interesting problem, I worked out what such a more complex solution would look like:

```
select min(A) as A, B from (
  select decode(A <> nvl(min(A) over (order by DRB, DRA rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),-1), true, 'good', 'no good') as Y,
    A, B from (
    select dense_rank() over (partition by B order by A) as DRA,
      dense_rank() over ( order by B) as DRB,
      A, B from <table>
  )
  where DRA <= DRB
)
where Y = 'good'
group by B
order by A, B;
```

Comment: Thank you @Bill Weiner . It looks promising but I am not sure I understand it. Any clarification would be helpful.

Comment: I started with ranking of the Bs and a ranking of As for each B.  Now we know that for the lowest ranked B we will want the lowest ranked A for the B value - this leads to the where clause that the rank of A (within B values) has to be equal to or less than the B rank.  In this same select I order the rows by these rankings and window over the A values finding if the current A matches the minimum A for preceding rows - this A, B combo has been used before.  This sets a flag as to lowest unused B for each A.  Lastly I grab the "good" flagged rows and group by B to find the min A that matches.